# Login & Register modal

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, semantic-ui

I've created two form in different php files one is Login form and other is Register form, Then there is two Login and Register buttons in the menu
How can i make these buttons shows their forms in modal?

Comment: Please edit your question with the minimum HTML / CSS /Javascript that pertains to the question you are asking. Also include what you have already attempted to give those helping you a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with an ajax query so I gonna give you an example that how you can do it:

The HTML and JS:

```
<body>
  <div id="my_modal" class="modal"></div>
  <button  onclick="showLoginModal()">Login</button>
  <button  onclick="showRegisterModal()">Register</button>
</body>
<script>
      function showLoginModal(){   
          $.ajax({
            url:'php/login_content.php',
            type:"GET",
            cache:false,
            success:function(html){
              $("#my_modal").html(html);
              $('#my_modal').modal();
            }
          });
          event.preventDefault();
      }
      function showRegisterModal(){   
          $.ajax({
            url:'php/register_content.php',
            type:"GET",
            cache:false,
            success:function(html){
              $("#my_modal").html(html);
              $('#my_modal').modal();
            }
          });
          event.preventDefault();
      }
</script>
```

The login_content.php file:

```
<?php ?><div class="modal-content">
<form action="" method="post">
    User
    <input name="user_name" id="user_name" type="text"> Password
    <input name="user_pass" id="user_pass" type="password">
    <button type="submit" id="login">Login</button>
</form>
```

The register_content.php file:

```
<?php ?>
<div class="modal-content">
<form action="" method="post">
 Username
    <input name="user_name" id="user_name" type="text"> 
 Password
    <input name="user_pass" id="user_pass" type="password"> 
 Confirm Password
    <input name="user_pass" id="user_pass" type="password">
    <button type="submit" id="login"> Register</button>
</form></div>
```

Greetings!

Comment: why not just call `$('#myModal').load('login_content.php')` or `register_content.php` depending on which button was clicked (could be set via something like a `data-` attribute?

Comment: @Jhecht That`s is a valid response too, the mine is just one

Answer (score 0):

I'll flesh out my comment on Darwin's answer a little more so you can see what I am talking about.

Now, I warn you about having a fallback way to get the user to the login page just in case javascript doesn't work for whatever reason (and there are many reasons why it wouldn't), but that being said.

***The code here is not entirely correct as it involves multiple files, for a full working demo please go to [This Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4xQXgCf4iaranxmjHbqb?p=preview)***

```js
// Code goes here

$(function() {
  $('.modal-btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = this.id;
    $('#login-register-modal').load(id + '_content.html', function(response, status) {
      if (status == 'success')
        $('#login-register-modal').modal();
    });


  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#">Link                 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown                 <span class="caret"></span>
              </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">One more separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button id="login" class="btn btn-default modal-btn">Login</button>
          <button id="register" class="btn btn-default modal-btn">Register</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div id="login-register-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

## Register_content.html

```
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h2>Register</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">

    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputEmail3">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputPassword3">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword1" placeholder="Password" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputPassword3">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword2" placeholder="Password" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
      Close
    </button>

  </div>
</div>
```

## Login_content.html

```
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    Login
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">

    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputEmail3">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputPassword3">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" /> Remember me
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
      Close
    </button>

  </div>
</div>
```